# coq - applying the inductive hypothesis to a hypothesis in eqb_list_true_iff

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic

I am working my way through the software foundations book in my free time and this problem is particularly challenging for me. Here is where it gets stuck:

```
Fixpoint eqb_list {A : Type} (eqb : A -> A -> bool)
                  (l1 l2 : list A) : bool :=
  match l1, l2 with
  | [], [] => true
  | [], _ => false
  | _, [] => false
  | (l1' :: l1s'), (l2' :: l2s') => (eqb l1' l2') && (eqb_list eqb l1s' l2s')
  end.

Lemma eqb_list_true_iff :
  forall A (eqb : A -> A -> bool),
    (forall a1 a2, eqb a1 a2 = true <-> a1 = a2) ->
    forall l1 l2, eqb_list eqb l1 l2 = true <-> l1 = l2.
Proof.
  intros. split.
  - intro. induction l1 as [|l1' l1s' IHl'].
  + destruct l2. { reflexivity. } { simpl in H0. discriminate H0. }
  + induction l2 as [|l2' l2s' Il2h']. { simpl in H0. discriminate. } { simpl in H0. }
Abort.
```

And here is the proof state...

```
1 subgoal
A : Type
eqb : A -> A -> bool
H : forall a1 a2 : A, eqb a1 a2 = true <-> a1 = a2
l1' : A
l1s' : list A
x : A
l2 : list A
H0 : eqb l1' x && eqb_list eqb l1s' l2 = true
IHl' : eqb_list eqb l1s' (x :: l2) = true ->
       l1s' = x :: l2
______________________________________(1/1)
l1' :: l1s' = x :: l2
```

I can easily isolate `eqb l1' x` and do some rewriting below to get the heads of the lists (`l1'` and `x`) to be equal, but the tails (`l1s` and `l2`) are killing me. My gut says that by applying `IHl'` to `H0` somehow I can move forward, but I cannot figure out a way to universally qualify the induction hypothesis, nor can I find a way to massage `H0` to make it resemble `IHl'`. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The induction hypothesis is too weak. Informally, you could expect that part of the proof to go like this:

> We want to prove `l1 :: l1s = x :: l2'`, for that it is sufficient to prove:
>
> 1. `l1 = x` (using the assumption on the `eqb` parameter), and
> 2. `l1s = l2'`.

That latter claim should somehow follow from the induction hypothesis. The induction hypothesis should thus say something about comparing `l1s` and `l2'`. However `IHl'` in your current goal is about comparing `l1s` with `x :: l2'`.

The problem is that the first `induction l1` is done on the goal "`l1 = l2`": at that point `l2` is fixed, so in the inductive case, the induction hypothesis is going to compare the tail of `l1` with `l2`, rather than with the tail of `l2`.

In short, the goal is too specific to be proved directly by induction. It must be generalized first. The Tactics chapter (*Varying the induction hypothesis*) of Software Foundations explains how to address this issue.

(I'm intentionally not giving away the actual solution as this is a homework question, but feel free to ask for further clarification.)

Comment: Don't you mean that the induction hypothesis is too weak? (It implies fewer conclusions than the correct one.)